# Forwarding request from one controller method to another controller method, the BindingResult is empty

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have 2 controllers with 2 methods. In one of the methods I validate my Bean and populate the BindingResult object. I then add my bean in to model and forward the request to another controller like mav.addObject("forward:"+ControllerA.url). When the other method receives it, the BindingResult object is empty. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I learned the hard way you can't redirect/forward a request and expect the BindingResults to follow.  Each time a Controller is called, it does its own binding.  The first call, you are missing parameters/etc, so Spring generates those errors and puts them in BindingResults.  However, at this point you have a ModelAttribute object.  Now you do the forward/redirect.  Spring makes the call, but now the ModelAttribute exists...there is no binding, so no BindingResults.